# knockoutjs pass parameters in nested foreach binding

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to pass the property of an outer object in a nested foreach loop to a function. 
This would be the `'something'` in the code below, but I can't even get it working with a hardcoded string:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: supportedNetworks">  

       <div  data-bind="text: $data"></div>

       <div class="span3 social_connect text-right">

       <div data-bind="with: $root.Selected">
           <div data-bind="foreach: networks">          
                 <div id='connected' data-bind="text: $root.checkNetwork.bind($data,'something')">
                </div>

           </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

This displays `function () { [native code] }` in the `'connected'` div

My ultimate goal is to have the list of networks displayed and foreach one of them, check if the current user is connected, by comparing with his list of networks and show the appropriate message.

My model is like this:

```
function viewModel() {

        var self = this;         

        self.supportedNetworks = ['facebook', 'twitter', 'google'];   

        self.checkNetwork = function (name) {
            console.log(name); 
            // Display connected or Not connected          
        };                      

        ....
  };
```

The selected object is a user object having networks of the type:

```
function SocialNetwork(item) {
    var self=this;

    self.Id = ko.observable(item.Id),
    self.Name = ko.observable(item.Name)   
};
```

Am I close at all? Btw, I'm using version 2.3.0 if it matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `.bind` creates a new function that is executed with a specific context and arguments. So, the result of `.bind` is a function, which you could then execute by adding `()` after it.

However, in this case (using the `text` binding) it looks like you want the output of the function call, so you could simplify it to just:

```
data-bind="text: $root.checkNetwork('something')"
```

Comment: I missed this one. So the full expression I want is  data-bind="text: $root.checkNetwork($data.Name(),$parents[1])">